# React-Redux, passing reference to container method many levels deep?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The solution I can up with works-i'm wondering if there is a better way. Basically, I am passing onDelete down as props from CoursesPage > CourseList > CourseListRow. CourseListRow is where onDelete is being triggered, and I am passing the id of the course I want to delete, to the deleteCourse function in the CoursesPage container component via event.target.value.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Does using context make sense in this case?

Render method in container component:

*CoursesPage.js*

```
render() {
    const {courses} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        <input type="submit"
               value="Add Course"
               className="btn btn-primary"
               onClick={this.redirectToAddCoursePage}/>

        <CourseList
                courses={courses}
                onDelete={this.deleteCourse}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

1st Level:

*CourseList.js*

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import CourseListRow from './CourseListRow';

const CourseList = ({courses, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Length</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {courses.map(course =>
        <CourseListRow key={course.id} course={course} onDelete={onDelete}/>
      )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

CourseList.propTypes = {
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default CourseList;
```

2nd Level:

*CourseListRow.js*

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

const CourseListRow = ({course, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td><a href={course.watchHref} target="_blank">Watch</a></td>
      <td><Link to={'/course/' + course.id}>{course.title}</Link></td>
      <td>{course.authorId}</td>
      <td>{course.category}</td>
      <td>{course.length}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          type="submit"
          name="deleteCourseButton"
          onClick={onDelete}
          value={course.id}
        > Delete </button>
      </td>

    </tr>
  );
};

CourseListRow.propTypes = {
  course: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default CourseListRow;
```

Comment: Why add context? How about just dispatching your delete action from CourseListRow?

Comment: Thought of that, I didn't do it because I was trying to keep with the convention of container components handling redux...you would just dispatch the action from CourseListRow?

Comment: The way you have it, or dispatching from the Row are your best options, and both are fine. 'dumb' components are more reusable, but that's a tradeoff you have to decide what is worth

Answer (score 1):

If you using redux for store and react-redux for connection between components and store, in most cases you shouldn't pass props deeper than one level (some times you may not pass them at all). This tutorial is kinda handy: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Simplified example, assuming you familiar with redux and saw react-redux API:

It is better to use isolated components and use connectors.

```
 // assume, that CoursesList is your App
 <Provider store={store}>
   <CoursesList/>
 <Provider>
```

After this you connect each component which uses data from store.

```
// CoursesListContainer.js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CoursesList from './CoursesListComponent.js'

function mapStateToProps(state) { return state.courses; }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursesList);
```

At the very deep of ypur app you will make container for button:

```
//DeleteButtonContainer.js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import actionCreators from './actionCreators'
import DeleteButton from './DeleteButtonComponent';

function mapStateToProps() { return {};}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    onClick: () => dispatch(actionCreators.deleteCourse(ownProps.id))
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DeleteButton);
```

in your row you simply import non ButtonComponent, but ButtonContainer and set id as props.